# Apache restart on Ubuntu - error "could not bind to address 0.0.0.0.80"

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I'm a n00b - trying to get apache2 set up on Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala) on Rackspace Cloud. I have set up/configured OpenSSL and installed Apache, but Apache won't start. I assume its a misconfiguration in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl or  /etc/apache2/sites-available/default files)

When I try to restart apache using the command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I get the following error message:

[error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name *.80 -- ignoring!
[error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name *.80 -- ignoring!
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
   ...fail!

For my /etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl I have used a virtual host of *:443.

For my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default i have used a virtual host of *:80

Comment: you will get better responses for this type of question at serverfault.com - voted to move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off Skype. It's use port number 80 for incoming messages. Eventually check what use this port at the moment using `netstat`.

Second resolve is simply: Add `ServerName localhost` to main config. file.

Comment: Wow! This answer really saved me some time! Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check /etc/hosts. Be sure that your machine name and localhost domain definition is correct (ie: "127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain   localhost"
2. However it is highly unlikely, check /etc/apache2/ports.conf if it contains explicitly "0.0.0.0"