# Apache 2 error and phpmyadmin not working after installation on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I installed PHPMyAdmin via apt-get on my Ubuntu and I set the directory in apache2.conf, but when starting the server, nothing happens when `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` access and the following message appears I my console:

```
    juninho-desktop:~$ /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
                                                                         [fail]
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

This is my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file:

http://pastebin.com/yafW00S6

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache restart on Ubuntu - error "could not bind to address 0.0.0.0.80"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404732/apache-restart-on-ubuntu-error-could-not-bind-to-address-0-0-0-0-80)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission problems, try to restart apache2 using root priviliges:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Apache works, but when I enter / phpmyadmin the error appears 404 not found

Comment: The directory you've included on the last line supposed to be empty. Try to look for phpmyadmin.conf in directory 'apache2/sites-enabled'. Don't forget to restart apache2 after instalation. As far as I can see, you didn't restart it properly.

Answer (score 1):

you could type:

```
netstat -lnptu
```

in your terminal. Then look for a programm that is blocking the Port 80.
This programm needs to be closed or must use another port :)